# XPath for table

Tags: xml, xpath

I have such xml:

```xml
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><div class="SelectBox"></div></th>
            <th tabindex="0"><div>ID</div></th>
            <th><div>NAME</div></th>
            <th><div>City</div></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="SelectBox"></div></td>
            <td><div>id-10341</div></td>
            <td><div>Anna</div></td>
            <td><div>London</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="SelectBox"></div></td>
            <td><div>id-10249</div></td>
            <td><div>Eva</div></td>
            <td><div>Paris</div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to define xpath to a cell with class `SelectBox` in a line containing text `id-10249`

I tried to use this way, but it didn’t help.

`//tbody//*[contains(text(),'id-10249')]//parent::tr//div[@class='SelectBox']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a variant of an XPath:

//tbody/tr[td/div[contains(text(),'id-10249')]]/td/div[@class='SelectBox']

You select tr elements which satisfy the condition for contaning text in div element and than search inside this tr element for div element with a specified class.

Comment: Thank you! But I changed your method to `//tbody/tr[td//*[contains(text(),'id-10249')]]//*[@class='SelectBox']`.